# Zoomable time series in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Highcharts has a feature where you can select a section of a time series graph to zoom in on that section (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does d3 provide a similar ability, or is there a plug on module somewhere that provides for this?

Comment: were you able to implement something that would aggregate the data on zoomout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know this is what you can use in D3 :[Zoom Behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior)
Example: [Zoom Behaviour Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254)

How you use it is upto you. You can also apply zoom transitions to give it proper effects. Alternatively if it is ok for you to draw a subchart/viewfinder below your main chart you can use D3 brush: [d3.svg.brush() Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)

I hope this helps you achieve similar effect as you showed.